# Upload Picture to REST API in Unity

Tags: c#, rest, unity-game-engine, file-upload

I would like to ask on how to upload an image to REST API that accept image as parameters, from unity. The REST API is developed separately, and tested with postman, [Like This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7HE0.jpg). Since we can upload image successfully using postman, then the problem lies in Unity.

These are my codes to upload (sourceTex is the image (Texture2D) to upload):

```
public void UploadClicked () {
    statusText.text = "UPLOADING";
    DBManager.API.UpdateProfilePicture(sourceTex.GetRawTextureData(),
        (response) =>
        {
            statusText.text = "UPLOAD SUCCESS";
        },
        (error) =>
        {
            statusText.text = "UPLOAD ERROR";
        }
    );
    
}
```

And here are the codes from the class that handles the REST API:

```
public void UpdateProfilePicture(byte[] texData,
    System.Action<string> onComplete , System.Action<string> onError = null)
{
    string url = config.restURL + config.updateProfilePicture; //this is the REST URL
    WWWForm data = new WWWForm();
    data.AddBinaryData("profilePictureImage",texData,username+"Pic.png","image/png");
    Dictionary<string,string> header = CreateHeaderWithAuthorization ();//create the header here            
    PostRequest(url,data.data,header,onComplete, onError);
}


WWW PostRequest(string url, byte[] data, Dictionary<string,string> postHeader, System.Action<string> onComplete, System.Action<string> onError) {
    WWW www;
    www = new WWW (url, data, postHeader); 

    StartCoroutine (WaitForRequest (www, onComplete, onError,debugIndex));
    return www;
}


IEnumerator WaitForRequest(WWW www, System.Action<string> onComplete, System.Action<string> onError,int debugIndex) {
    while (!www.isDone) {
        yield return null;
    }
    if (www.error == null) {
        if (onComplete != null)
            onComplete (www.text);
    } else {
        if (onError != null)
            onError (www.error + "|" + www.text);
    }
}
```

But I get

```
"error":"Cannot cast object 'org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@7352ae54' with class 'org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade' to class 'org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartHttpServletRequest'",
"stacktrace":{
"suppressed":[
  
],
"message":"Cannot cast object 'org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@7352ae54' with class 'org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade' to class 'org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartHttpServletRequest'",
"class":"org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException",
"stackTraceDepth":119,
"cause":null,
"localizedMessage":"Cannot cast object 'org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@7352ae54' with class 'org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade' to class 'org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartHttpServletRequest'",
"stackTrace":[
{
     "className":"org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.DefaultTypeTransformation",
     "fileName":"DefaultTypeTransformation.java",
     "lineNumber":405,
     "methodName":"continueCastOnSAM",
     "nativeMethod":false
  },
  {
     "className":"org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.DefaultTypeTransformation",
     "fileName":"DefaultTypeTransformation.java",
     "lineNumber":319,
     "methodName":"continueCastOnNumber",
     "nativeMethod":false
  },
  {
     "className":"org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.DefaultTypeTransformation",
     "fileName":"DefaultTypeTransformation.java",
     "lineNumber":232,
     "methodName":"castToType",
     "nativeMethod":false
  },
  {
     "className":"org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter",
     "fileName":"ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java",
     "lineNumber":603,
     "methodName":"castToType",
     "nativeMethod":false
  },
  {
     "className":"com.bidroyal.api.v1.UserController",
     "fileName":"UserController.groovy",
     "lineNumber":706,
     "methodName":"$tt__uploadProfilePicture",
     "nativeMethod":false
  },
  {
     "className":"com.bidroyal.api.v1.UserController$_uploadProfilePicture_closure14",
     "fileName":"UserController.groovy",
     "lineNumber":-1,
     "methodName":"doCall",
     "nativeMethod":false
  },
  {
     "className":"sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl",
     "fileName":"NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java",
     "lineNumber":-2,
     "methodName":"invoke0",
     "nativeMethod":true
  },
  {
     "className":"sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl",
     "fileName":"NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java",
     "lineNumber":62,
     "methodName":"invoke",
     "nativeMethod":false
  },
  {
     "className":"sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl",
     "fileName":"DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java",
     "lineNumber":43,
     "methodName":"invoke",
     "nativeMethod":false
  },
  {
     "className":"java.lang.reflect.Method",
     "fileName":"Method.java",
     "lineNumber":498,
     "methodName":"invoke",
     "nativeMethod":false
  },
  {
     "className":"org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod",
     "fileName":"CachedMethod.java",
     "lineNumber":93,
     "methodName":"invoke",
     "nativeMethod":false
  },
  {
     "className":"groovy.lang.MetaMethod",
     "fileName":"MetaMethod.java",
     "lineNumber":325,
     "methodName":"doMethodInvoke",
     "nativeMethod":false
  },
  {
     "className":"org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass",
     "fileName":"ClosureMetaClass.java",
     "lineNumber":294,
     "methodName":"invokeMethod",
     "nativeMethod":false
  },
  {
     "className":"groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl",
     "fileName":"MetaClassImpl.java",
     "lineNumber":1027,
     "methodName":"invokeMethod",
     "nativeMethod":false
  },
  {
     "className":"groovy.lang.Closure",
     "fileName":"Closure.java",
     "lineNumber":414,
     "methodName":"call",
     "nativeMethod":false
  },
  {
     "className":"groovy.lang.Closure",
     "fileName":"Closure.java",
     "lineNumber":430,
     "methodName":"call",
     "nativeMethod":false
  },
  {
     "className":"grails.transaction.GrailsTransactionTemplate$2",
     "fileName":"GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy",
     "lineNumber":96,
     "methodName":"doInTransaction",
     "nativeMethod":false
  },
  {
     "className":"org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate",
     "fileName":"TransactionTemplate.java",
     "lineNumber":133,
     "methodName":"execute",
     "nativeMethod":false
  },
  {
     "className":"grails.transaction.GrailsTransactionTemplate",
     "fileName":"GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy",
     "lineNumber":93,
     "methodName":"execute",
     "nativeMethod":false
  },
  {
     "className":"com.bidroyal.api.v1.UserController",
     "fileName":"UserController.groovy",
     "lineNumber":-1,
     "methodName":"uploadProfilePicture",
     "nativeMethod":false
  },
  {
     "className":"org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass$MethodHandleInvoker",
     "fileName":"DefaultGrailsControllerClass.java",
     "lineNumber":223,
     "methodName":"invoke",
     "nativeMethod":false
  },
  {
     "className":"org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass",
     "fileName":"DefaultGrailsControllerClass.java",
     "lineNumber":188,
     "methodName":"invoke",
     "nativeMethod":false
  },
  {
     "className":"org.grails.web.mapping.mvc.UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter",
     "fileName":"UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter.groovy",
     "lineNumber":90,
     "methodName":"handle",
     "nativeMethod":false
  },
  {
     "className":"org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet",
     "fileName":"DispatcherServlet.java",
     "lineNumber":963,
     "methodName":"doDispatch",
     "nativeMethod":false
  },
  {
     "className":"org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet",
     "fileName":"DispatcherServlet.java",
     "lineNumber":897,
     "methodName":"doService",
     "nativeMethod":false
  },
  {
     "className":"org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet",
     "fileName":"FrameworkServlet.java",
     "lineNumber":970,
     "methodName":"processRequest",
     "nativeMethod":false
  },
  {
     "className":"org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet",
     "fileName":"FrameworkServlet.java",
     "lineNumber":872,
     "methodName":"doPost",
     "nativeMethod":false
  },
  {
     "className":"javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet",
     "fileName":"HttpServlet.java",
     "lineNumber":648,
     "methodName":"service",
     "nativeMethod":false
  },
  {
     "className":"org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet",
     "fileName":"FrameworkServlet.java",
     "lineNumber":846,
     "methodName":"service",
     "nativeMethod":false
  },
  {
     "className":"javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet",
     "fileName":"HttpServlet.java",
     "lineNumber":729,
     "methodName":"service",
     "nativeMethod":false
  },
  {
     "className":"org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain",
     "fileName":"ApplicationFilterChain.java",
     "lineNumber":292,
     "methodName":"internalDoFilter",
     "nativeMethod":false
  },
  {
     "className":"org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain",
     "fileName":"ApplicationFilterChain.java",
     "lineNumber":207,
     "methodName":"doFilter",
     "nativeMethod":false
  },
  {
     "className":"org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter",
     "fileName":"WsFilter.java",
     "lineNumber":52,
     "methodName":"doFilter",
     "nativeMethod":false
  },
  {
     "className":"org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain",
     "fileName":"ApplicationFilterChain.java",
     "lineNumber":240,
     "methodName":"internalDoFilter",
     "nativeMethod":false
  },
  {
     "className":"org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain",
     "fileName":"ApplicationFilterChain.java",
     "lineNumber":207,
     "methodName":"doFilter",
     "nativeMethod":false
  },
  {
     "className":"javax.servlet.FilterChain$doFilter$0",
     "fileName":null,
     "lineNumber":-1,
     "methodName":"call",
     "nativeMethod":false
  },
  {
     "className":"grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.RestLogoutFilter",
     "fileName":"RestLogoutFilter.groovy",
     "lineNumber":80,
     "methodName":"doFilter",
     "nativeMethod":false
  },
  {
     "className":"org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain",
     "fileName":"ApplicationFilterChain.java",
     "lineNumber":240,
     "methodName":"internalDoFilter",
     "nativeMethod":false
  },
  {
     "className":"org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain",
     "fileName":"ApplicationFilterChain.java",
     "lineNumber":207,
     "methodName":"doFilter",
     "nativeMethod":false
  },
  {
     "className":"org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter",
     "fileName":"ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java",
     "lineNumber":55,
     "methodName":"doFilterInternal",
     "nativeMethod":false
  },
  {
     "className":"org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter",
     "fileName":"OncePerRequestFilter.java",
     "lineNumber":107,
     "methodName":"doFilter",
     "nativeMethod":false
  },
  {
     "className":"org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain",
     "fileName":"ApplicationFilterChain.java",
     "lineNumber":240,
     "methodName":"internalDoFilter",
     "nativeMethod":false
  },
  {
     "className":"org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain",
     "fileName":"ApplicationFilterChain.java",
     "lineNumber":207,
     "methodName":"doFilter",
     "nativeMethod":false
  },
  {
     "className":"org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter",
     "fileName":"WebRequestTraceFilter.java",
     "lineNumber":105,
     "methodName":"doFilterInternal",
     "nativeMethod":false
  },
  {
     "className":"org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter",
     "fileName":"OncePerRequestFilter.java",
     "lineNumber":107,
     "methodName":"doFilter",
     "nativeMethod":false
  },
  {
     "className":"org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain",
     "fileName":"ApplicationFilterChain.java",
     "lineNumber":240,
     "methodName":"internalDoFilter",
     "nativeMethod":false
  },
  {
     "className":"org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain",
     "fileName":"ApplicationFilterChain.java",
     "lineNumber":207,
     "methodName":"doFilter",
     "nativeMethod":false
  },
  {
     "className":"org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain",
     "fileName":"FilterChainProxy.java",
     "lineNumber":317,
     "methodName":"doFilter",
     "nativeMethod":false
  },
  {
     "className":"org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor",
     "fileName":"FilterSecurityInterceptor.java",
     "lineNumber":127,
     "methodName":"invoke",
     "nativeMethod":false
  },
  {
     "className":"org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor",
     "fileName":"FilterSecurityInterceptor.java",
     "lineNumber":91,
     "methodName":"doFilter",
     "nativeMethod":false
  },
  {
     "className":"org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain",
     "fileName":"FilterChainProxy.java",
     "lineNumber":331,
     "methodName":"doFilter",
     "nativeMethod":false
  },
  {
     "className":"org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter",
     "fileName":"ExceptionTranslationFilter.java",
     "lineNumber":115,
     "methodName":"doFilter",
     "nativeMethod":false
  },
  {
     "className":"org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain",
     "fileName":"FilterChainProxy.java",
     "lineNumber":331,
     "methodName":"doFilter",
     "nativeMethod":false
  },
  {
     "className":"javax.servlet.FilterChain$doFilter",
     "fileName":null,
     "lineNumber":-1,
     "methodName":"call",
     "nativeMethod":false
  },
  {
     "className":"grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.RestTokenValidationFilter",
     "fileName":"RestTokenValidationFilter.groovy",
     "lineNumber":118,
     "methodName":"processFilterChain",
     "nativeMethod":false
  },
  {
     "className":"sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor879",
     "fileName":null,
     "lineNumber":-1,
     "methodName":"invoke",
     "nativeMethod":false
  },
  {
     "className":"sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl",
     "fileName":"DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java",
     "lineNumber":43,
     "methodName":"invoke",
     "nativeMethod":false
  },
  {
     "className":"java.lang.reflect.Method",
     "fileName":"Method.java",
     "lineNumber":498,
     "methodName":"invoke",
     "nativeMethod":false
  },
  {
     "className":"org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce",
     "fileName":"PogoMetaMethodSite.java",
     "lineNumber":210,
     "methodName":"invoke",
     "nativeMethod":false
  },
  {
     "className":"org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite",
     "fileName":"PogoMetaMethodSite.java",
     "lineNumber":59,
     "methodName":"callCurrent",
     "nativeMethod":false
  },
  {
     "className":"org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite",
     "fileName":"AbstractCallSite.java",
     "lineNumber":190,
     "methodName":"callCurrent",
     "nativeMethod":false
  },
  {
     "className":"grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.RestTokenValidationFilter",
     "fileName":"RestTokenValidationFilter.groovy",
     "lineNumber":84,
     "methodName":"doFilter",
     "nativeMethod":false
  },
  {
     "className":"org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain",
     "fileName":"FilterChainProxy.java",
     "lineNumber":331,
     "methodName":"doFilter",
     "nativeMethod":false
  },
  {
     "className":"org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter",
     "fileName":"SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java",
     "lineNumber":169,
     "methodName":"doFilter",
     "nativeMethod":false
  },
  {
     "className":"org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain",
     "fileName":"FilterChainProxy.java",
     "lineNumber":331,
     "methodName":"doFilter",
     "nativeMethod":false
  },
  {
     "className":"javax.servlet.FilterChain$doFilter",
     "fileName":null,
     "lineNumber":-1,
     "methodName":"call",
     "nativeMethod":false
  },
  {
     "className":"grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.RestAuthenticationFilter",
     "fileName":"RestAuthenticationFilter.groovy",
     "lineNumber":143,
     "methodName":"doFilter",
     "nativeMethod":false
  },
  {
     "className":"org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain",
     "fileName":"FilterChainProxy.java",
     "lineNumber":331,
     "methodName":"doFilter",
     "nativeMethod":false
  },
  {
     "className":"grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter",
     "fileName":"MutableLogoutFilter.groovy",
     "lineNumber":62,
     "methodName":"doFilter",
     "nativeMethod":false
  },
  {
     "className":"org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain",
     "fileName":"FilterChainProxy.java",
     "lineNumber":331,
     "methodName":"doFilter",
     "nativeMethod":false
  },
  {
     "className":"grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.SecurityRequestHolderFilter",
     "fileName":"SecurityRequestHolderFilter.groovy",
     "lineNumber":58,
     "methodName":"doFilter",
     "nativeMethod":false
  },
  {
     "className":"org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain",
     "fileName":"FilterChainProxy.java",
     "lineNumber":331,
     "methodName":"doFilter",
     "nativeMethod":false
  },
  {
     "className":"org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy",
     "fileName":"FilterChainProxy.java",
     "lineNumber":214,
     "methodName":"doFilterInternal",
     "nativeMethod":false
  },
  {
     "className":"org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy",
     "fileName":"FilterChainProxy.java",
     "lineNumber":177,
     "methodName":"doFilter",
     "nativeMethod":false
  },
  {
     "className":"org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain",
     "fileName":"ApplicationFilterChain.java",
     "lineNumber":240,
     "methodName":"internalDoFilter",
     "nativeMethod":false
  },
  {
     "className":"org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain",
     "fileName":"ApplicationFilterChain.java",
     "lineNumber":207,
     "methodName":"doFilter",
     "nativeMethod":false
  },
  {
     "className":"org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter",
     "fileName":"GrailsWebRequestFilter.java",
     "lineNumber":77,
     "methodName":"doFilterInternal",
     "nativeMethod":false
  },
  {
     "className":"org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter",
     "fileName":"OncePerRequestFilter.java",
     "lineNumber":107,
     "methodName":"doFilter",
     "nativeMethod":false
  },
  {
     "className":"org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain",
     "fileName":"ApplicationFilterChain.java",
     "lineNumber":240,
     "methodName":"internalDoFilter",
     "nativeMethod":false
  },
  {
     "className":"org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain",
     "fileName":"ApplicationFilterChain.java",
     "lineNumber":207,
     "methodName":"doFilter",
     "nativeMethod":false
  },
  {
     "className":"org.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter",
     "fileName":"HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java",
     "lineNumber":67,
     "methodName":"doFilterInternal",
     "nativeMethod":false
  },
  {
     "className":"org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter",
     "fileName":"OncePerRequestFilter.java",
     "lineNumber":107,
     "methodName":"doFilter",
     "nativeMethod":false
  },
  {
     "className":"org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain",
     "fileName":"ApplicationFilterChain.java",
     "lineNumber":240,
     "methodName":"internalDoFilter",
     "nativeMethod":false
  },
  {
     "className":"org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain",
     "fileName":"ApplicationFilterChain.java",
     "lineNumber":207,
     "methodName":"doFilter",
     "nativeMethod":false
  },
  {
     "className":"org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter",
     "fileName":"CharacterEncodingFilter.java",
     "lineNumber":197,
     "methodName":"doFilterInternal",
     "nativeMethod":false
  },
  {
     "className":"org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter",
     "fileName":"OncePerRequestFilter.java",
     "lineNumber":107,
     "methodName":"doFilter",
     "nativeMethod":false
  },
  {
     "className":"org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain",
     "fileName":"ApplicationFilterChain.java",
     "lineNumber":240,
     "methodName":"internalDoFilter",
     "nativeMethod":false
  },
  {
     "clas...."
```

So I'm at lost on where should I fix my code. I've tried couple variations, like EncodeToPNG(), or other no MIME type, it's still the same. Even EncodeToPNG() won't work if Read/Write properties is not enabled. But how did I do that, if the image file can came anywhere from device?

Thanks.

Comment: your rest api want image as byte array or file ?

Comment: I'm not really sure, maybe file? If you look at the postman screenshot, can you determine what it is?

In any case, with my (limited) knowledge of WWWForm, there are only 2 methods, AddField or AddBinaryData. Is there any other way that I'm unaware of?

Comment: Did you set the Content-Type header to `undefined`?

Comment: For other APIs, I'm using JSON, so the Content-Type is set to application/json. But, if you see from postman screenshot, there are 3 headers (which is usually 4 in others), which is: appKey, appSecret, and Authorization. All three has been set. There's no Content-Type header on postman, and since it's image and not json, I thought it was normal not to set Content-Type.

Should I set it manually? If so, what should I put there?